# I want to add a class to the parent of the drop-down box depending on a dynamically added class to the drop-down box using jQuery

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, dynamically-generated

I want to add a class to the parent of the drop-down box depending on a dynamically added class to the drop-down box using jQuery.But unsuccessful. Could help me to sort out this problem. Following are my code.

```
<label>Exp.Date</label>
                                 <div class="selectWrapper">
                                    <select name="expmonth" class="exp-month required" data-error-message="Please select a valid Expiry Month!">
                                    <?php get_months(); ?>
                                    </select>
                                 </div>[The ui look like the following][1]
```

jQuery I have used below:

```
$(".exp-month").on("change", function(){
            if($(this).hasClass("no-error")){
                $(this).parent(".selectWrapper").addClass("error_free");
            }else{
                $(this).parent(".selectWrapper").removeClass("error_free");
            }           
        });
```

The `no-error`class added dynamically when I have choose some month from drop-down and it's removed when I choose default value - 'Month' from the drop-down.

Depending on the `no-error` class I want to add the class `error_free` to the parent element of the drop-down but unable to do them correctly.
Meanwhile, when the above code run, it's added my class when no-error not available and vice versa. Moreover it's not work when the drop-down change using keys.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
$(".exp-month").on("change", function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("no-error")){
        $(this).closest(".selectWrapper").addClass("error_free");
    }else{
        $(this).closest(".selectWrapper").removeClass("error_free");
    }           
});
```

Comment: According to your html there is no such class found "no-error". can you add manually and test?